# Change end of filename using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to change the number at the end of a image path on click.

```
$(".container-button").click(function(){
    $("img.picture").each(
            function(){
                var p = $(this).attr('src');
                var new_image = p.replace('3.jpg' || '2.jpg' || '1.jpg', '4.jpg');
                $(this).attr('src',new_image);
            }
        );
});
```

If you take a look at my code I do the following:

- on click i search the class for the image source and store it in a variable
- I create a new variable that looks for the end of the image file for a set of filenames, replaces it with 4.jpg, and stores it in a variable new_image.
- I look for the source attribute and switch it for what is stored in new_image.

What im seeing is that it only looks to replace if it finds the first filename in the set but the others are ignored.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.replace(/[123]\.jpg$/i, '4.jpg')`

Comment: This expression `'3.jpg' || '2.jpg' || '1.jpg'` will evaluate to '3.jpg' and that's why only that gets replaced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OR condition will stop after evaluating the first string `'3.jpg'` and will ignore the others.

To use OR in regex, you can use `|` operator.
So, `(1|2|3)\.jpg` can be used. However, character class is bit fast and range can be used in it.

```
$(".container-button").click(function() {
    $("img.picture").attr('src', function(i, value) {
        return value.replace(/[1-3]\.jpg$/i, '4.jpg');
    });
});
```

Other than that, `attr()` can be used with callback function to change the `src` attribute of all the matched elements.

The RegEx `/[1-3]\.jpg$/i` will match

1. A number between 1 and 3
2. Followed by `.` character(This need to escape to match literal)
3. Followed by `jpg` at the end of the string.
4. The `i` flag is used to match the string case-in-sensitively.

Comment: Thank you. I see i misused the or condition and this regex solution worked perfectly!